# Animate div from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im try to get a div to slide from the left hand side so it looks like it slides out.

Currently i have it expanding out from the top left corner which is close but not what i am after.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/yhdrfo4e/

html:

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

js:

```
$( ".first" ).click(function() {
  $( ".second" ).show( "slow" );
    $( ".first" ).hide( 100 );
});

$( ".second" ).click(function() {
  $( ".second" ).hide( "slow" );
    $( ".first" ).show( 100 );
});
```

CSS:

```
.first{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
}

.second{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You may find jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) useful.

Comment: See the [slide demo here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).

Comment: I made it work, below ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments using `animate()` may help to achieve what you're looking for.

Here is an example of an animation to show/hide the divs after click:

```
$( ".first" ).click(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: 0}, {duration: 1000});
    $(this).hide();
    $(".second").show();
    $(".second").animate({width: 400}, {duration: 1000});
});

$( ".second" ).click(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: 0}, {duration: 1000});
    $(this).hide();
    $(".first").show();
    $(".first").animate({width: 100}, {duration: 1000});
});
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhdrfo4e/8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".first" ).click(function() {
  $( ".second" ).show().animate({width: '400px'});
  $( ".first" ).animate({width: 0}).hide();
});

$( ".second" ).click(function() {
  $( ".first" ).show().animate({width: '100px'});
  $( ".second" ).animate({width: 0}).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhdrfo4e/7/

Slightly different way of looking at it:

```
$( ".first" ).click(function() {
  $( ".second" ).show().animate({width: '400px'});
  $( ".first" ).animate({width: 0}, function (){$(this).hide()});
});

$( ".second" ).click(function() {
  $( ".first" ).show().animate({width: '100px'});
  $( ".second" ).animate({width: 0}, function (){$(this).hide()});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhdrfo4e/9/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Ok, it was a blast:

```
$( ".first" ).one('click' , function() {
  $( ".second" ).show().animate({width:400}, 800);
  $( ".first" ).animate({width:0,left:400}, 800 ).promise().done(function(){
    $(this).hide( );         
    second();
  });
});

function first() {
    $( ".first" ).one('click' , function() {
      $( ".second" ).show().animate({width:400}, 800);
      $( ".first" ).animate({width:0,left:400}, 800 ).promise().done(function(){
        $(this).hide( );         
        second();
      });
    });
}


function second() {
    $( ".second" ).one('click' , function() {
      $( ".second" ).animate({width:0}, 800 ).promise().done(function(){
        $(this).hide( );
        first();
      });
      $( ".first" ).show( ).animate({width:100,left:0}, 800);
    });
}
```

CSS

```
div {
  position:absolute;
}
```

What this does, is to make a switch with `.one()`, which is a once `.on()` (`click` here). http://api.jquery.com/one/

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhdrfo4e/11/**

Comment: It looks cool but it is very buggy after you click a couple of times.

Comment: Your two handlers need to mirror each other. Right now, both disappear once you click on it a couple of times.

Comment: @Dan Haha, funny. It slowly blows into smithereen!

Comment: @Dan I gave everything!!

Comment: @JaredFarrish Let me have a look of yours. ;)

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've given an answer, if that was meant to be snarky. I was giving advice because I thought it was interesting, but it needed to be fixed. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, yes. needed to. Doctored with `$('body').data('two', false)` etc. switches for a while. Thought the result was worth looking. ;) Greetings!! Looks **all** good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

Begin with the second div visible, but off-screen (set 'left' to negative width of div -- assuming div is placed at left edge of DOM. Otherwise, set left to [negative width of div] + [distance to left edge of window])

Use `animate()` to hide/move the first div off-screen.

Then, in the callback for the first animation (which means this next bit will happen only AFTER the first bit finishes), slide the second div to 'left'=0px

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8sj7up/)</kbd>

**jquery/js**:

```
$('.first').animate({
    opacity:0,
    left: '-100px'
},1000,function(){
    $('.second').animate({
        left: '0px'
    },1000);
});
```

**css:**

```
.first{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

.second{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:-400px;
}
```

---

In answer to your comment question, to make the process happen on click just trap the click event on the desired element. For example, suppose you have an input type=button:

```
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

The javascript would be:

```
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('.first').animate({
        opacity:0,
        left: '-100px'
    },1000,function(){
        $('.second').animate({
            left: '0px'
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: See extra explanation added to bottom of answer.